# Solr Server is not starting in rails in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, solr

I am using rake sunspot:solr:start to start solr server & it displays Successfully started Solr ...
but when I browse localhost:8982 , it doesn't display anything.
Yesterday , my applciation was ruuning fine but not it is not working .
I also tried to find existing solr id by using command lsof -i :8982 , but it doesn't show anything .
I also deleted solr folder from my app & then executed rake sunspot:solr:start , it doesn't works for me.

Comment: Did you change port in `sunspot.yml`?

Comment: Yes , I have tried with port 8984 & some other ports but it doesn't works

Comment: A wild guess, if you are working on multiple rails projects and using SOLR for each one, then, the port for SOLR for each project must be different, else, if SOLR is already running for one project, then for other project it will say **successfully started solr...** but it won't work.

Comment: No , I am having a single rails project with solr.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Configure-Solr-on-Ubuntu,-the-quickest-way) may help

Comment: No , the above is not working .Also , what is the need to install tomcat as I am using gem sunspot_solr & sunspot_rails for this. From the link given by u , i have installed tomcat & solr but I am not able to login in my app..I have use port 8080 in development mode in sunspot.ym